# Using javascript or python regular expressions I want to determine if the number is 1-99 how to make it?

Tags: javascript

```
var category = prompt("where do you go? (1~99)", "");
```

hello

Using regular expressions I want to determine if the category is 1-99.

How can I solve it?

Thank you if you let me know.

Comment: Why not simply use a if statement ? i.e. `if( x >= 1 && x <= 99)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use character classes to match digits, like this `[0-9]`. If you put two of them together you'll match 00 - 99. If you put a `?` after one of them, then it's optional, so you'll match 0 - 99. To enforce 1-99, make the non-optional one like this `[1-9]`. Finally, you need to make sure there's nothing before or after the one or two digits using ^, which matches the beginning of the string, and $ which matches the end.

```
if (category.match(/^[1-9][0-9]?$/)){
    console.log("ok")
} else {
    console.log("not ok")
}
```

Comment: Note that `match` requires a regex, not a string. It will be implicitly converted, but it's better practice to use a regex `/^[0-9][1-9]?$/`.

Comment: Very elegant regex BTW, +1.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know my question. It works well. thank you~!

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you can use test() method with RE for 1-99 as shown below:

```
var one_to_ninetynine = /^[1-9][0-9]?$/i;

if(one_to_ninetynine.test(category)) {
    console.log("The number is between 1-99");
} else {
    console.log("The number is NOT between 1-99");
}
```

Comment: thank you for good answer I'll try it too It seems intuitive too